# MySQL full text não encontra resultados com sublinhado

Tags: mysql, full-text

Estou usando o `MATCH/AGAINST` do [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) para implementar um sistema de busca, o problema é que, palavras com sublinhado **(ex: lista_compras_mercado.txt)** são interpretadas como uma só, existe alguma forma de transformar sublinhados em "**separadores"** de palavras? como o espaço?

Comment: você já olhou o replace() do Mysql

Comment: replace("meu_texto_aqui","_"," ")